# javaScript problems with NaN and += operator

Tags: javascript

first off thanks for taking the time. I'm working on an IBU calculator for beer making. Please see the comment below. parseB is a text input converted to a number I've seen the typeof ibuFinal is a number and the inBU[i] is also a number. why is it returning Nan?

```
var AAU=[]; 
var og=1.050;   
for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
    util[i]=(1.65*Math.pow(0.000125, og-1))*(1-Math.exp(-0.04*parseB[i]))/4.15;;                   
}

            function aau(){
                for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
                    AAU[i]=weight[i]*alpha[i];

                }
                return AAU;
            }

            function ibu(){

                var alphaAcid=aau();
                var inBU=[];
                var ibuFinal;

                for(var i=0;i,alphaAcid.length;i++){

                    inBU[i]=alphaAcid[i]*util[i]*75/batchSize;

                    ibuFinal+=inBU[i];//returns NaN for some reason!!
                }

                alert(ibuFinal);
            }
            ibu();
```

Comment: Be careful : `typeof NaN` is `"number"`...

Comment: You never define `ibuFinal`, so it's `undefined`. `undefined + 1` (or any number) is `NaN`.

Comment: I would put alerts around the first line in the for loop, to make sure I got into the loop, and then to make sure inBU got set. What if something in alphaAcid, util or batchSize comes up as null or zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never define `ibuFinal`, so it's `undefined`.

The [type-coercion in JavaScript's addition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) works out that `undefined + 1` (or any number) is `NaN`. (In EMCAScript terms, [`ToNumber(undefined)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) is `NaN`, and `NaN` plus anything is `NaN`.)

Make sure you initialize `ibuFinal` to zero: `var ibuFinal = 0;`

Comment: Yup, that'll do it. Thanks a ton!